# Customizing resource routes for every action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, custom-routes

I have a `resources :posts`. How can I customize it's paths to the following and also ability to call it with the normal resource path names:

```
URL          Controller action      Helper function
'q'          'posts#index'          posts_path
'q/(:id)'    'posts#show'           post_path(:id)
'ask'        'posts#new'            new_post_path
'q'          'posts#create'         posts_path
```

Here is what I've tried and doesn't work as the expected result above...

```
get 'q' => 'posts#index', as: :posts
get 'q/(:id)' => "posts#show", as: :post
get 'ask' => 'posts#new'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're presumably getting an error because you're trying to assign a route name that is already in use.

The `resources posts` call results in a definition for the `posts` and `post` routes. If you change your `as: ..` clause to reference different (unused) names, you will no longer get that error.

Answer (score 0):

try `resources :posts path => 'q'`